# ng-click not working, dont know why

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Hey, I've been trying to solve this problem and searching on the web has got no results. For some extrange reason ng-click has stopped working on my project.

This is my routes

```
$stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html'
        })
        .state('tables', {
            url: '/tables',
            templateUrl: 'templates/tables.html',
            controller: 'MasterCtrl'
        });
```

The controller function

```
    angular.module('module')
    .controller('MasterCtrl', ['$scope', '$cookieStore', MasterCtrl]);

    function MasterCtrl($scope, $cookieStore) {

    $scope.doSomething = function(){
        alert("HEYYYY");
    };
}
```

And the html button

```
 < button ng-click="doSomething()">clickMe!< /button>
```

I really dont know why it wouldn't work, earlier in the week it was working fine

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: missing parentheses, `ng-click="doSomething() "`

Comment: Try `doSomething()` in your HTML.

Comment: It still wont work, i've tried both ways

Answer (score 1):

Function should be represented witha  paranthesis, change it as follows,

```
< button ng-click="doSomething()">clickMe!< /button>
```

Comment: You probably can't have spaces between `<` and `button`. Or `<` and `/button>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller=“MasterCtrl”>
   <button ng-click=“doSomething()”>click me</div>
</div>
```

Try the above code in html.

Comment: I think this is wrong - `ng-click` takes an expression like `doSomething()`

Comment: @FrankModica. I really missing ()

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must have forgotten something...

```js
(function () {

  'use strict'
  
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MasterCtrl', ['$scope', MasterCtrl])
  
  function MasterCtrl ($scope) {
      $scope.doSomething = function() {
        alert('clicked!')
      }
    }

})()
```

```html
<html ng-app='app'>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="MasterCtrl">
   <button ng-click="doSomething()">click me</div>
</div>

</html>
```